# How to return the latest 10 values (Rows) using query in google sheets?

Tags: date, sorting, google-sheets-formula

I've been trying to return the latest 10 dates, but it's bringing wrong data:

`=QUERY('DB Queried'!A4:G,"select A order by A Desc Limit 10")`

Resulting in:
[image]

...where there should be dates in the month of May, for example.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct for me, with formatted dates
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your dates are in text format and are sorted as text not as date.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't rely on formatting of data. It literally gets the last 10 values in Column A as they appear, without the need to sort the data.

`=query({'DB Queried'!$A:$G},"select Col1 offset "&ARRAYFORMULA((LOOKUP(2,1/('DB Queried'!$A:$A<>""),ROW('DB Queried'!$A:$A))))-10&" ",0)`

If you did want to sort the data, you could wrap another `QUERY` around:

`=query(query({'DB Queried'!$A:$G},"select Col1 offset "&ARRAYFORMULA((LOOKUP(2,1/('DB Queried'!$A:$A<>""),ROW('DB Queried'!$A:$A))))-10&" ",0),"where Col1 is not null order by Col1",0)`

or desc:

`=query(query({'DB Queried'!$A:$G},"select Col1 offset "&ARRAYFORMULA((LOOKUP(2,1/('DB Queried'!$A:$A<>""),ROW('DB Queried'!$A:$A))))-10&" ",0),"where Col1 is not null order by Col1 desc",0)`

**Notes**

`QUERY` function uses a SQL like syntax to manipulate the data.

The first argument is the range that you want to query. Which in this case is inserted with the [array notation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en) `{'DB Queried'!$A:$G}`.

`offset` allows you to ignore x number of values, which in this case is the total number of rows of data, less 10, so you only see the last 10 rows. The total number of rows is determined by `ARRAYFORMULA((LOOKUP(2,1/('DB Queried'!$A:$A<>""),ROW('DB Queried'!$A:$A))))` which gets the row number of the last value, then `-10`.